# how do you test ngFormController in angular controller tests?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

ngFormController is created for you when you give a form a name.

`<form name="accountForm">` will create $scope.accountForm and this allows you to do things like `$scope.accountForm.$setPristine()`

However, in my controller tests `accountForm` is undefined because I suppose it's created after the template is parsed and I'm not sure the template is even considered when testing the controller.  How can I mock this up in the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this same issue. What I ended up doing was using sinon.stub to make a fake form object. This object had these properties:

```
form = {$valid: true, $pristine: false, $dirty: true, $setPristine: function () {scope.newItemForm.$dirty = false, scope.newItemForm.$pristine = true;}};
```

I then set that fake to equal my scope's newItemForm.

```
scope.newItemForm = form;
```

I then tested to see if the behavior was correct, whether `scope.newItemForm.$dirty = false and scope.newItemForm.$pristine = true` when `$setPristine` was triggered and the opposite when it wasn't supposed to be triggered.

This doesn't mock all the behaviors of `$setPristine`, but I figure I just need to know if the method is triggered since I shouldn't be concerned about testing angular's functionality.

Comment: What we wanted to test was a series of expectations on $setPristine, $dirty on input fields, for client and server error, validations etc.  But it was getting messy in the controller.  So we abandoned that idea and pushed the logic in a directive.  From there it is arguably easier to get access to the formController because the ngModel on the input will register itself with the parent ^form.